# Build a C++ repository with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm struggling to build this github repo: https://github.com/thorbenk/saliencyfilters. Running the suggested build line doesn't work. Running `cmake ..` from the build/ dir, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.
```

Yet I do provide "FindOpenCV.cmake" in the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH -- here it is in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project(saliency)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
find_package( TBB )

find_package( PythonLibs REQUIRED )
find_package( Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED )
find_package( VIGRA REQUIRED )

add_definitions( -std=c++11 )

add_subdirectory (src)
```

Note the author specifically requested not to be bothered with install issues, so I'm requesting help here :)

Comment: `Note the author specifically requested not to be bothered with install issues` => I suggest you not to use it

Comment: Try: `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)`. Then remove and redo the build dir and try again.

Comment: In case try to change `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` with `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`.

Comment: Try with `cmake .. -DOpenCV_ROOT_DIR=/%PATH_TO_OpenCV_SOURCE%/`

Comment: Thank you @fedepad for the suggestions, but the same error occurs.

Comment: Same for @Shravan40's suggestion.

Comment: 1. What does `message("Path: ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")` output? 2. Is the case of your filename correct?

Comment: @oLen (1) `Path:`, so nothing. (2) yes.

Comment: Got it! Issue was setting my PATH to find the correct package -- `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/opencv3/bin:$PATH"`